# Activate the frontmost Safari and run Javascript

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I'm trying to run Javascript on the Safari, whose frontmost is true.

```
tell (application "Safari" whose frontmost is true) to do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
```

But I get an error like this:

```
execution error: Can’t get application "System Events" whose frontmost of it = true. Access not allowed. (-1723)
```

where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Your script is trying to tell s.th. to a Safari application allegedly ***already "frontmost"***. Is it?!?
You can only identify or activate an ***unknown*** element by property ("whose ... is ...")
This will do: ***the first*** application whose ...

*If you WANT* "Safari" to become "frontmost" you'd  better write:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
end tell
```